# Question - What is the pearson correlation between average dew point and average temperature? my code:

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, jupyter

This is my Code *

corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(data['Average dewpoint (°F)']data['Average temperature(°F)'])

corr = "corr = " + str(round(corr_matrix[1][0], 2))

corr

Error:----

File "<ipython-input-9-2d98b56652c2>", line 1
corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(data['Average dewpoint (°F)'], data['Average temperature
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

I have try several methods , But didnt find this !

Comment: Could you indent your code properly please? and wrap code blocks with `\`\`\`` top and bottom

Comment: If your code really is all on one line you will get a SyntaxError exception (invalid syntax) but not the EOL error that you report (unless this issue is reported differently in an out-of-date Python version)

Comment: my code is line by line wait let me edit this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(data['Average dewpoint (°F)'],data['Average temperature (°F)'])

corr = "corr = " + str(round(corr_matrix[1][0], 2))

corr

The above worked for me.